# Pandas: category dtype and filter

Tags: python, pandas, filter, categorical-data

using pandas 0.18.1, I realized a different behavior when filtering a column whose `dtype` is `category`. Here is a minimal example.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

l = np.random.randint(1, 4, 50)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(c_type=l, i_type=l))
df['c_type'] = df.c_type.astype('category')

df.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 50 entries, 0 to 49
Data columns (total 2 columns):
c_type    50 non-null category
i_type    50 non-null int64
dtypes: category(1), int64(1)
memory usage: 554.0 bytes
```

Filtering out one of the value of the integer type columns leads to

```
df[df.i_type.isin([1, 2])].i_type.value_counts()

2    20
1    17
Name: i_type, dtype: int64
```

but the same filtering on the category type column keeps the value filtered as an entry

```
df[df.c_type.isin([1, 2])].c_type.value_counts()

2    20
1    17
3     0
Name: c_type, dtype: int64
```

Although the filter works, the behavior seems unusual to me. The filter could be used, for example, to exclude future columns from a `pivot_table` function which requires an extra filter when dealing with `category`.

Is it an expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is expected behavior, if check [categorical docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html#operations):

> Series methods like **Series.value_counts()** will use all categories, even if some categories are not present in the data:

```
In [100]: s = pd.Series(pd.Categorical(["a","b","c","c"], categories=["c","a","b","d"]))

In [101]: s.value_counts()
Out[101]: 
c    2
b    1
a    1
d    0
dtype: int64
```

So if filter by `5` (value is not in present) get `0` for each category:

```
print (df[df.c_type.isin([5])].c_type.value_counts())
3    0
2    0
1    0
Name: c_type, dtype: int64
```